# Separator lines appearing around UITableViewCell on select/highlight in iOS8

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, ios8

I have a very simple UITableView where I have set the separator inset style to be none:

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
```

Running the app I get what I expect with no lines between the cells. However, when I select one of the table view cells, white lines appear around it. Why is that and can I change the appearance of it? Screenshots below:

[image]
[image]

The lines shown by arrows appear on highlight. The cell colour change is intentional. Any help in the right direction would be much appreciated. I am using iOS 8.1 as target with XCode 6.1.1

I have set the background colour as follows.
In viewDidLoad:

```
tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
tableView.alpha = 0.8
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
thisCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
thisCell.contentView.alpha = 0.85
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are overriding setSelected and setHighlighted?

```
self.selectedBackgroundView.hidden = true
```

works for me.

It took me a while to find a solution to it as well. And this is the view hierarchy that I found for the cell:

```
0: class: 'UITableViewCellSelectedBackground'
0: class: 'UITableViewCellContentView'    
0: class: '_UITableViewCellSeparatorView'
```

The UITableViewCellSelectedBackground is setting the background. The background is then overlayed with the ContentView.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please say how you made such background in cells? In my opinion it's not selection lines, it just whole grey background, that appear under you cell black backgrounded view while section or highlighting. You could use debug view heresy or just override this two functions:

1. `func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool)`
2. `func setHighlighted(highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool)`

Comment: Hi Alex, I have edited the question to add details of how the tableView background colour and the cell's background colour is set.

Comment: Have you tried to override methods above in my answer?

Comment: Yes, just did. Overriding these two functions results in these lines momentarily appearing when I tap on the cell and the disappear. But doesn't get rid of it completely. Also found that if I set shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath to false, then it does achieve the effect of removing the lines but also removes the effect of colour change on cell selection.